Voltage readings in water electrolysis
I have a water electrolyzer stack of five cells, six stainless steel electrodes of surface area $729\ \mathrm{cm}^2$, electrolyte used is $\ce{KOH}$ at $5\ \%$ concentration. When I supply it with a battery of $12\ \mathrm V$, the electrolyzer terminals read $10.3\ \mathrm V$ and $10.8\ \mathrm A$; when connecting two $12\ \mathrm V$ batteries in series, the electrolyzer reads $11\ \mathrm V$ and $40\ \mathrm A$; when connecting to $24\ \mathrm V$/$10\ \mathrm A$ power supply it reads $10.3\ \mathrm V$ and $8.8\ \mathrm A$; and when connecting to $12\ \mathrm V$/$20\ \mathrm A$ power supply, it reads $10\ \mathrm V$ and $7.2\ \mathrm A$.
Why doesn't it accept any more potential difference across its terminals, why doesn't it get the full $20\ \mathrm A$ of the $12\ \mathrm V$ power supply and why is the surge of current when connecting two batteries in series while the voltage stays at $11\ \mathrm V$?

The electrolyzer has differential resistance roughly 0.02 Ohm, that is comparable to expected internal resistance of lead acid batteries. By other words, you have caused almost the short circuit for the serialised batteries, taking more than one half of the short circuit current.

Why don't you simulate both the electrolyzer and any of used power supply by combination of an ideal voltage source and internal resistence? Values of respective voltages and resistances can be derived from open and closed circuit voltage and current reading.

There are a few limiting factors for current through the electrolyzer:

Each cell has a potential to overcome, about 1.5 VDC to start electrolysis.
An additional overvoltage is added to speed up the reaction, but wasting energy as heat.
Insulating bubbles form as electrolysis proceeds, and the electrolysis cells heat up, having opposing effects on current draw. Further, as the reaction proceeds, the concentration of $\ce{KOH}$ in solution changes. Therefore, expect that current will change with time, perhaps unpredictably as bubbles form and break.
A battery or power supply has a maximum short circuit current. For example, measuring the current with a low-resistance ammeter across a 12 V battery with internal resistance of 0.1 Ω would show a current of 12 A, with effectively no voltage dropped across the ammeter -- 12 V at 12 A is being wasted in the battery, heating it with 144 W. See Ohm's law.
If one battery can deliver a maximum of 12 A through a short-circuit, two or even 1,000 of those batteries in series can only deliver 12 A.

You might try using exactly the same batteries in parallel to increase current. However, do not put regulated power supplies in parallel because one might output 12.00 V and the other 12.01 V, and the higher voltage device will take all the load, or even try to force current backwards into the other supply.

Thanks for your reply. Can you provide an explanation why the reading of the electrolyzer across its terminals was 11v when supplied by two 12v batteries connected in series as mentioned and 40 amps drawn in this case. We tried connecting both batteries in parallel as well, the reading was 8-10 ampere range, which is the same reading or close to it when connecting one of the batteries alone. Please note that the batteries are both lead acid but not the same brand nor the same capacity 8AH and 23AH
